# Can any one explain the meaning of orderby line of SQL in below code?

Tags: sql

Could anyone please explain the meaning of orderby line in below code?

```
SELECT winner, subject
FROM nobel
WHERE year=1984
ORDER BY subject IN ('Chemistry', 'Physics'),subject,winner
```

Comment: Run the query and see the difference by keeping and eliminating it.

Comment: TRUE > FALSE, Chemistry and Physics will be sorted at the end.

Comment: @dileepsai . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.  This is not standard SQL.

Answer (score 1):

This is a boolean expression:

```
subject IN ('Chemistry', 'Physics')
```

In databases that support booleans, this evaluates to "true" or "false" or `NULL`.  In such databases, "true" is equivalent to `1` and "false" to `0`.

Hence, this puts those subjects after all other subjects:

```
Literature     false  --> 0
Economics      false  --> 0
Chemistry      true   --> 1
Physics        true   --> 1
```

The standard construct would use `case`:

```
order by (case when subject in ('Chemistry', 'Physics') then 1 else 0 end),
          . . .
```

The use of booleans like this is fine.  However, I almost always use a `desc` sort so the TRUE values go first.

Answer (score -1):

You are ordering to keep Chemistry and Physics values as the priority of sort order, followed by other subjects and winner

Comment: TRUE > FALSE, Chemistry and Physics will be at the end. (I'm not the one downvoting.)

Answer (score -1):

You are sorting the data of subject and winner based on their alphabetic order and it is good to use subject IN ('Chemistry', 'Physics') in where clause not with order by